# Separator Character with Multi-Select Parameter

Tags: sql, string, csv, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS to pass a multi-select parameter to a stored procedure, for this I'm using a string splitting function in the stored procedure (relevant lines below).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerformance] (
@ItemName varchar(max)
)
...

SELECT Item
INTO #ItemNames
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@ItemName,',');

SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE ItemName IN(SELECT Item FROM #ItemNames)
```

This works fine, until one of the items in the list contains a comma, then I get no results. Ie: If in my SSRS report, the user selects these items:

```
Apples
Bananas
Grapes, Strawberries, and Melons
Oranges
```

In the stored procedure, I end up with the following:

```
Apples
Bananas
Grapes
Strawberries
and Melons
Oranges
```

and all of the relevant rows are excluded. Is there a way to change the character used by SSRS join multi-select parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the ItemID instead of the name. @R. Richard's answer of double/replacing the commas could have worked, but using IDs seems more logical.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here would be to replace the commas in the dropdown list values to something else, like a semicolon maybe. Handle that in the stored procedure, too, by doing a `REPLACE` on the data at run time. This is the path of least resistance.

SQL to fill the dropdown:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(ItemName, ',', ';') AS ItemName FROM SomeTable
```

Stored procedure change:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPerformance] (
@ItemName varchar(max)
)
...
SELECT Item
INTO #ItemNames
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@ItemName,',');

SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE REPLACE(ItemName, ',', ';') IN (SELECT Item FROM #ItemNames)
```

Or, just remove the commas from the data. Change that category to something else, if you can. Probably not the most desirable option, but if you can convince the data owner to make the change, then you may not have to worry about changing the report.

The comma in the list for an `IN` clause is universal. Changing the delimiter in SSRS, if it were even possible, would break reports that use the `IN` clause, but don't use stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could work, but I instead opted to use IDs.

Comment: Event better! Good that is an option. Sometimes all you have is a description field.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, using Id's is the preferred option. 
But sometimes you have no choice but to use data items with commas embedded into the data values themselves.
In this case, consider wrapping each item in your list with a qualifier like double quotes.
Then tweak your "split" routine to handle the qualifier. 
So my code to supply the parameter would look like;

```
Select Label = myField, Value = '"' + myField + '"' From myTable;
```

And my split function looks like;

```
Create Function fn_SSRS_Split
    (@Parameters Varchar(Max), @Qualifier varchar(10))
    Returns @Result Table (Value varchar(8000))
As
Begin
    Declare @Value Varchar(Max), @Pos Int
    Declare @Search Varchar(10), @SearchLength Tinyint, @QualifierLength Tinyint;

    -- Default Delimiter and Qualifier parameters if blank or null
    Set @Delimiter          = IsNull(NullIf(@Delimiter, ''), ',');
    Set @Qualifier          = IsNull(NullIf(@Qualifier, ''), '"');
    Set @QualifierLength    = DataLength(@Qualifier)
    Set @Search             = @Qualifier + @Delimiter;
    Set @SearchLength       = Len(@Search);

    Set @Parameters         = @Parameters + @Delimiter

    Set @Pos = CharIndex(@Search, @Parameters, 1)

    While @Pos > 0 
    Begin
            Set @Value = Right(Left(@Parameters, @Pos - (@SearchLength - 1)), @Pos - ((@SearchLength - 1) * 2))
            If @Value <> ''
                Insert Into @Result (Value) Values (@Value) 
            Set @Parameters = SubString(@Parameters, @Pos + @SearchLength, DataLength(@Parameters) - @Pos - 1)
            Set @Pos = CharIndex(@Search, @Parameters, @SearchLength)
    End 
    Return
End
```